# cannot remove null values during extractions of values with json extractor

Tags: json, jmeter

"id": 23751775{  },
"id": null,
"id": null,
"id": 23751567{  },

Need to extract id that are not null with json extractor and leave null values out so i can use other values for future use.
i have tried multiple regex but was not successfull

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to provide the comprehensive answer without seeing your JSON, but theoretically you can omit the matches with the unwanted values using [Filter Operator](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators).

For example given this JSON:

```
{
  "store": {
    "book": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      {
        "id": null,
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  },
  "expensive": 10
}
```

and this [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression

You can see that only 3 matches are being returned there `id` attribute is having its respective value:

[image]

and when the condition is not there it will give you 4 matches and one value will be empty:

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)